# Degree of a field extension $F[x]/(g(x))$ over the field $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and let $F[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in $x$ over $F$. Let $g(x)$, of degree $n$, be in $F[x]$ and let $V=(g(x))$ be the ideal generated by $g(x)$ in $F[x]$.
I have to prove that $F[x]/V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$.
Help me with the proof.

Comment: $g$ irreducible must be missing

Comment: @marwalix: no this is not necessary. Notice that $F[x]/V$ doesn't have to be a field.

Comment: Hint: prove that $$\{1+V,x+v,\dots,x^{n-1}+V\}$$ is a basis of $F[x]/V$ over $F$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!